# How to call one javascript variable to another javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTMLForm which on click forward me to new HTML page i have Two `JS` files for each HTML

**What i am doing and trying to achieve is :-**

- On 1st HTML when i click `search` button i am storing the values of input field and select field in different variables
- What I am trying to achieve is when on search new page loaded I want to use that new variable into my new JavaScript
- I have Two HTML files also

here is the code of my `file1.html`

```
<form id="formId" action="file2.html">
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Date:</h4>
            <input type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276"
                placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
            <h4>Outlets:</h4>
            <select name="outlet" id="myselect">
                <option>ALL</option>
            </select>
            <div>
                <br>
                <button id="btn-search" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Search
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/JavaScript1.js"></script>
```

- In This HTML i have a form  having one date field and one select field
- On clicking submit Button I am Storing the values of `date` and `Outlet` into a variable in my JavaScript file which is `JavaScript1`

**Here is my JavaScript1 file **

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#btn-search").click(function(){  
       var   currentlyClickedOutletform = $("#myselect").find(":selected")[0].textContent;
       var   currentlyClickedStartdateform= $("#startdate").val();                
          $.ajax({
                url : "LinkReportMain",
                method : "POST",
                data : {
                       Outletlink : currentlyClickedOutletform,  
                       Fromdatelink : currentlyClickedStartdateform,                            
                     },                          
            });

    });

});
```

`var currentlyClickedOutletform` and `var currentlyClickedStartdateform` are the two values i want to use in my new JavaScript file which is JavaScript2

**my file2.html is**

- in this  file i am just populating an HTML table so i only have an div tag inside

`<div id="tbl"></div>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/JavaScript1.js"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/JavaScript2.js"></script>`

**And finally my JavaScript2 is**

- in this file I want to use the values of first Javascript file

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert(currentlyClickedOutletform)
  $('.loader').show();
  $('.overlay').show();
  $.ajax({
    url: "LinkReportMain",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {
      fromdate: $("#startdate").val(),
      todate: $("#enddate").val(),
      outlet: $("#all").val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
      let formatedData = formatData(data);
      renderTable(formatedData);
      $('.loader').hide();
      $('.overlay').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

**NOTE** to see the code of JavaScript2 file please see the snippet its not working but my code was not getting formatted so I have put that into snippet

So what I am trying to achieve is to use the Variable of JavaScript1 into JavaScript2

i am doing it right but its not working any one out here who can guide em please, it would be very helpfull

Comment: redirect page with get parameter

Comment: @DhruvRaval how can you show me some code?

Comment: okay i add example

Comment: When you load new page (html 2) your memory for html 1 (js 1 file) doesn't exists anymore. So if you want to share some informations between html pages you can use localStorage, cookie, sessions...
Just set, let's say, variables in localStorage and use them in your second page.

Comment: @Deathmras some source of code would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Without localStorage**

First set `type="button"` of you search button or prevent form submit by `e.preventDefault();` on click event.

```
$("#btn-search").click(function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    // your other code

    //code to redirect to another html page
    var queryString = "?para1=" + currentlyClickedOutletform + "&para2=" + currentlyClickedStartdateform;
    window.location.href = "page2.html" + queryString;
})
```

for other page script:

```
var queryString = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search);
    queryString = queryString.substring(1);
    var oldParam = queryString.split("&");
    var param1 = oldParam[0];
    var param2 = oldParam[1];
```

Now you can use `param1` and `param2`.

**localStorage ** :

in first page store object :

```
localStorage.setItem("outletFrom",currentlyClickedOutletform);
localStorage.setItem("startDate",currentlyClickedStartdateform);
```

in seond page get data:

```
var currentlyClickedOutletform = localStorage.getItem("outletFrom");
var currentlyClickedStartdateform= localStorage.getItem("startDate");
```

Comment: hey which one should i prefer as per security reasons also?

Comment: if security level is password type then both are insecure.

Comment: yup i am using local storage..well i don't have knowledge about encryption